# Boolean Statements For Elements In Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

Suppose I have a list of coefficients of a polynomial in descending order of exponents (if `len(list) == x` then the exponents would range from integers x-1 to 0). I want to delete the "small" elements of said list, meaning `abs(element) > 0 and abs(element) < .000001` but keep the exponents of the polynomial that are not "small."

> How do I exactly do this in Python 3.0?

Here is an example of what I want in context:

``` my_list = [3.000000000000000e-12, 4.99999999999948, 4.00000000000002, -0.000042535500000e-15, -0.200000000000000]
exponents = [4,3,2,1,0] #As stated previously'
``>>> newlist = [4.99999999999948, 4.00000000000002, -0.200000000000000]
``>>> nexexp = [3,2,0] ```

Hence, the polynomial would be in the form
4.999999999999948*x^3 + 4.000000000000002*x^2 -0.200000000000000

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of deleting the small elements, keep the large ones:

```
newlist,newexp = zip(*[(x,e) for x,e in zip(my_list,exponents) if abs(x) > 1e-6])
```

You can use a filter, too:

```
newlist,newexp = zip(*filter(lambda x: abs(x[0]) > 1e-6, zip(my_list,exponents))))
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! There is one thing that I left out in my code: each of the exponents in the initial list are really the coefficients of a polynomial in descending order of exponents. I need to also find a way to only include the exponents of the coefficients that are not "small." Any way of doing that? In the example above, the desired list of exponents would be [3, 2, 0]. Thanks!

Comment: To get another answer, you have to ask another question or at least change the original question.

Comment: just finished modifying my question. It should be fixed, now.

Comment: `zip()` both lists, then filter as suggested above.

Comment: I'm very inexperienced when it comes to zip() and filter(). Could you perhaps elucidate more in the context of my case?